# Were punching tools for punch cards with rectangular holes easier to keep sharp than those for round holes?

Tags: history, ibm, mainframe, punched-cards

There is a question here on retrocomputing if round punch card holes where mechanically stiffer:

[Were round punchcard holes mechanically stiffer?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/16118/were-round-punchcard-holes-mechanically-stiffer)

I wondered if the reason for the rectangular holes on IBM's 80-line punch card was not the readability of the punch cards themselves, but the durability of the punching tools used to make the holes.

A punching tool that should create rectangular holes only has to be sharpened on one side, like a chisel, and then it is sharp again. If you use four of these that are of triangular shape and combine them to a forming rectangle, you can create a nice, sharp, rectangular hole.
And these four stamps could be sharpened very often, the longer the stamp tool, the more often that would be possible.

In the case of a round stamping die, the stamped piece is likely to be cut off first during manufacture, so that it is flat. In the next step, it gets an inner bore so that a hollow is created.
The outsides thus become sharp for clean cuts, but these outer cutting edge wear out more quickly. Such a punch can then no longer be repaired with simple methods, but must be exchanged for a new one.

Is that perhaps the main reason why IBM used rectangular holes so that the stamping tools can be reground more often and last longer?
A more detailed description of what the actual stamps looked like would be very revealing here. Macro Photos of the stamping tools would be super.

EDIT:
In this video from university of Nottingham proof is given, that a lot of punching did wear out the punch tools:
https://youtu.be/JafQYA7vV6s?t=114

Comment: I understand that the rationale for rectangular holes is closer packing, i.e., more data per square inch.  As [in this IBM history](https://www.ibm.com/ibm/history/ibm100/us/en/icons/punchcard/).

Comment: I doubt it, because if you make smaller round holes, you get the same density. And if you stagger the rows, you can increase the storage density with holes much more than with rectangles.

Comment: @another-dave It's competition. The highest packaging without changing the width is reached by round (or square) holes. Rectangular are sub optimal. In the end, the rectangular form only came due IBM keeping the vertical spacing as with the old cards but reducing the horizontal spacing to get 80 on the same card size. It would have been logical to go to round (or square) and either add more rows or more space inbetween.  Not doing so was not driven by physics or technology.

Comment: @Coder staggering wasn't a solution. Going from 40 to 80 holes per row was already increasing the character rate more than mechanical devices could handle. Remember the punch card was defined and implemented at a time when there was no fast (not even slow) electronics. In addition staggering would have meant to double the needed amount of mechanical contacts wich in turn needed to be operated in an alternating pattern. A rather unwelcome complication. Not to mention that all tools (key punch) would have to operate on alternating height when creating/editing.

Comment: @Coder Going from 40 to 80 cold be implemented for most parts with minor adjustment, like halving transport speed, the 'only' change being a wider data area in one card (which meant doubling processing capacity) but no principal change. Think of it like going from single sided disketes to double sided :))

Comment: Where is the proof in that video? That one peroson long ago (before they started to punch codes on paper tape)  said that this is what will happen is not a proof. A proof is if someone can give a figure of how often they had to change/sharpen the punches.

Comment: A square hole allows greater tolerance in the positioning. With a circular hole, a small error in the lateral position means that the longitudinal size of the hole reduces, while with a rectangular hole there is no loss in longitudinal accuracy if the lateral postioning is less than perfect.

Comment: @UncleBod They adjusted the code to the need. That should be more than necessary to have a proof.

Comment: @Coder No, the video says that "He said 'Look, if we are going to be punching holes coresponding to characters ...' ". He was (right or wrong) making an assumption from what he knew, but the video says nothing about anyone proving that the wear on the punches would be, or ever was, a problem. BTW, punched paper (and plymere) tapes were used paralell to punchcards, so the division was only that some media used round holes and some media used rectangual holes. (Might very well have been obscure uses of other hole types also).

Comment: @UncleBod You should listen more carefully to the video. The proof is clear in the video. He said in the second sentence: "Every time you punch one of these big holes it wears out that hole punch on your machine."  "Hole punch" means the tool.

Comment: @Coder Even if tehre is wear on the punch every time you use it, (everyone working in metal preparation knows that) it doesn't mean it will be a problem during the lifetime of the machine, or that you need to chenge the format of the holes, or that changing teh foramt of the holes will make things better.  The lifetime of the punch is given more from the material used in the punch and the possible after treatment (hardening,  tempering etc). Nothing in the video gives any indication of teh actual lifetiem of teh punches in "mean number of  holes punched between faliures".

Comment: @UncleBod The problem was big enough to create an encoding system in which characters that occur very frequently have as few holes as possible. If wear and tear hadn't played a significant role, as you claim, this effort would not have been made. You can also very well assume that people thought a lot about it at the time and recognized this as a major problem, for which they then saw this coding as a solution to alleviate this problem.

Comment: @Coder If wear was a significant problem, as you claim, why did they _later_ introduce 7 bit ASCII with parity bit, that would result in more wear? As I understand the video, the Murray code was the second code ever used, and probably the first used in automatic machines. The Murray code might have bben as early as from 1901.

Comment: @UncleBod ASCII wasn't introduced for punch cards, "modern" punch cards used mainly EBCDIC. ASCII was invented to have a interchangeable coding format between computers and printers. If you watch the other video of that channel about punch cards you will even hear, that ASCII is not used for punch cards, because too many holes would have weakened the card, thus ASCII is not practical for punch cards and therefore was not used for punch cards.

Comment: @Coder I didn't say it was. I said it was used for tapes (paper  and polymere). And I can assure you, it was a very large amount of tapes that were punched through the years.

Answer (score 9):

### TL;DR: NO.

For one,

- they are not cookie cutters but punches,

second

- they are hardened steel and very durable and

third, if they degrade,

- they will be simply exchanged - which includes *both* parts, punch and plate.

---

IBM punchcard holes are rectangular to keep competition at bay - as already described [in answers](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/16124/6659) to the cited question. 'Inventing' rectangular holes made the new form patentable (*1).

And no, there is no need for sharpening. I own keypunches that have been used for more than 30 years, stored for many decades and punch like on the first day. After all, why would they go dull? It's hardened steel against paper.

Also, [hardened steel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardened_steel) cannot be easily sharpened because it is quite brittle. It might also need to be rehardened, not a process in useful relation to the worth of that piece. They are throw away spare parts.

---

I would think the misconception here comes from the way you may assume them to work. Your description sounds much like a cookie cutter, a shaped blade pressed against a flat surface. But that's not the way (most) card punches work: They **punch** - that is a tool, called a punch, is pressed through the paper into a hole of the same shape and dimensions (*2). It works exactly like the good old [paper punch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punch) we all have used uncountable times. Here a schematic from [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hole_punch_workings_illustration.svg):

[image]

Do you remember having any of those ever sharpened? I don't. Cheap ones may go wobbly in their mechanics and thus lose function after a few decades of use, but not much more. I used one for many years which had been in that company since the early 1950s. Also, even the better ones have their cutting punches usually made from tempered steel, so less hard.

The principle used is the same as with a pair of scissors (when did you last sharpen those? (*3)) and called [shearing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shearing_(manufacturing)).

Same goes for key punches as mentioned - but also for hand punches. Some I own date back to the 1940s and have been in good use at least until the late 1970s.

---

*1 - Back in those times patent offices did really have their own engineers check application for having a minimum invention level.

*2 - That is a tiny bit bigger to avoid getting stuck.

*3 - Not talking about you grandma's iron ones but modern hardened steel.

Comment: Well, I was thinking about machines designed to punch new punch cards. There were certainly also copying machines and machines that were used like a printer for punched cards, while the data came from the computer. The endurance of the punching tool must be better if it is to punch millions of holes every day.
Of course, the programmer who only has to manually punch one card per minute doesn't need this durability, which depends on the type of hole if my assumptions are correct.

Comment: @Coder I'm not really sure what your image about a punches is. There were no cookie cutter type punches like you describe. There are manual punches, those are desktop thingies - which programmers may have used to do single cards. And there are gang punches, the fastest machines outputting cards. With a top speed of below 100 cards/min. With them operating 24 hours at full speed (which they could not)  they may hit one million holes. Real life usage was far away from your millions. And no, they did not need sharpening. They worked for years with minimal maintenance (mostly oil).

Comment: @Coder As mentioned, it's hardened tool and a hardened plate with a fitting hole, no cookie cutter. If necessary it would be replaced (never seen that happen). It was just a small metal piece. Not worth further attention.

Comment: @Coder Oh, and then there the key punch - which you seem to see as a lesser stressed device. **It isn't**.  Those typewriter like machines. Programmers did no use them. Programmers wrote on paper and let it be typed. That's data entry - you may have seen those pictures of halls filled with those machines and lots of young ladies typing. This is how all entry was done. Speed was between 10 and 20 cards a minute - yes, those gals were fast (also depends on data type). Programmers never typed themself. Bottom line, in real life those key punches were at least as much stressed as any gang punch.

Comment: In order to make a clean cut, these punches have to be sharp for a long time. It may just be soft paper, but any material wears out over time. This is also the case with water and hard rock. Water is soft and hard rock hard, but still it is able to destroy the rock over time. Sharper stamps also require less energy and allows for faster punching.
And of course these aren't kitchen knives that cut along a board, of course there are pre-made holes that they go into. But the stamps still wear out on the paper.

Comment: @Raffzahn - this programmer (as a university student) punched his own cards on an 029.

Comment: @Coder Yes, and at some time the Himalayan will be flat as the Midwest. But I do not think that either of us will live to that time. Situation is similar with card punch tooling. Speed ist not defined by how sharp a punch is - serious, what kind of process control do you expect? Sorry, I can only tell you from many years of experience with cards. ut if you don't believe the answer you got after asking, maybe visit a museum and look at one with your own eyes.

Comment: @another-dave My bad, I should have written 'professional programmers' ;))

Comment: @Raffzahn Watch https://youtu.be/JafQYA7vV6s?t=114 there it is said, the punch tool wears out. That's why they even used a code where the characters that occur very often needed the least holes. So your assumption is wrong.

Comment: @Raffzahn, *"It's hardened steel against paper."* - believe it or not, paper is a rather abrasive material. A personal hole-punch used for a few sheets a week may be serviceable for decades, but the cutting will degrade until fewer and fewer sheets can be accepted at once, more force must be applied (rapidly wearing the bearings of moving parts other than the cutting faces), and the cut becomes rougher.

Comment: @Coder Let me make this very clear: I'm not assuming. I am trained to that. I started my apprenticeship in mainframe maintenance in 1977 which at that times till included card punch equipment. Also, that video is apples and oranges, a theoretical view about basic considerations for a 1901 development (Murray code) isn't exactly transferring for 1940 and later technology.

Comment: @Steve Of course it does. But all is a matter of usage - a paper punch works with way more tolerance than a card punch - which also always does only a single sheet at once. The later also made of higher quality steel. Did I mention hardened? Paper hunches are usually not made of hardened steel. Last but not least, they will not be sharpened but exchanged like any failing mechanical part

Comment: Minor point: While I agree no one is going to try to sharpen a card punch (among other issues, they are way too small and fiddly to bother sharpening), it is normal to sharpen hardened steel tools. If you use appropriate stones you can easily put a new edge on a hardened steel cutting tool.

Comment: @MichaelKohne Yes, but this depends on several factors. First of all, through hardening, which is not possible for all material thickness. Normally hardening only influences the top layer due cooling properties. Next the the tool needs of a blade type and sharpening has to go from the opposite (non cutting) side of the tool. All of that works fine for straight blades like knifes of cutters, not at all for punch type tools, as neither the punch nor the plate (which are both cutting edges) can be sharpened without degrading the cut quality - all of that before talking about them being small :))

Comment: One thing not mentioned is that those things were built like _tanks_.  If you stuck two treads and some motors on them you could drive them into battle and they'd survive.  I'm talking of the ones I have experience with: 026 and 029.  I never saw one that needed maintenance.  Even the user-removable parts - like the cylinder you wrapped a template card around - couldn't possibly be broken by a squad of cocaine snorting orangutans.  Maybe the reader/punches that were machine peripherals were less robust.  The the ones you typed on couldn't be broken, didn't wear out - just kept on ticking.